# rewrite formula with sum to formula without sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing

I stumbeld into these formulas which are used to calculate the number of possible reflections in a rectangular enclosure.
How do I proof that the first formula equals the second one. 
$$\sum_{i=1}^k{N(N-1)^{i-1}} = N\frac{\left((N-1)^k-1\right)}{N-2}$$

Comment: Look at the sum of terms of a Geometric    sequence.

Comment: It's a geometric plum
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=1}^{k} r^{i-1} = \frac{r^k-1}{r-1} 
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thanks, this works for me.

Answer (score 1):

you remove the constant factor of N from the first, and then try to equate $\sum _{i=1}^k (N-1)^{i-1}$ with ${(N-1)^k-1\over N-2}$

Comment: It is sum from $i=1$ not i-1.

Comment: it wasn't when I made my answer I'll change it thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is straightforward to prove this by induction.

We can remove the constant $N$ from both sides and we have to prove $$\sum_{i=1}^k{(N-1)}^{i-1} = \frac{(N-1)^k-1}{N-2}.$$

Proof:

Firstly, we show that the equality holds for the base case, here $k=1$:
$$(N-1)^{0} = 1 = \frac{N-2}{N-2},$$
then for the inductive step we assume the equality holds for some $k=m$ and show that this implies it also holds for $k=m+1$:
$$\sum_{i=1}^m{(N-1)}^{i-1} = \frac{(N-1)^m-1}{N-2},$$
adding $(N-1)^m$ to both sides we have
$$\sum_{i=1}^{m+1}{(N-1)}^{i-1} = \frac{(N-1)^m-1}{N-2}+(N-1)^m \\
= \frac{(N-1)^{m+1}-1}{N-2}.$$
$$\tag*{$Q.E.D.$}$$

Comment: Consider posting this as a comment next time, as it doesn't really provide an answer to the question.

Comment: It is better to actually show how an inductive proof operates on such a formula than merely to claim "it is straightforward".  Please expand on your Answer.